# Is this negation correct for this statement?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

¬(for all n in N, there exists m in N, g(m,n))

equivalent to:

there exists n in N, for all m in N, ¬g(m,n)

Is that correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, that's correct. $$\lnot( \forall n \in \mathbb N, \exists m \in \mathbb N, g(m, n))\equiv \exists n \in \mathbb N, \forall m \in \mathbb N, \lnot g(m,n)$$

Comment: You can click on "edit" to the lower left of the answer to see how to format $\lnot, \exists, \forall, \mathbb N$ in MathJax.

Comment: Needs another TU! +1